# How to count instances of positive and negative differences of dataset

Tags: dataset, excel, google-sheets

I currently have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
|A1|A2|B1|B2|C1|C2|
-------------------
| 1| 3| 3| 4| 2| 2|
| 5| 4| 2| 3| 5| 5|
| 4| 1| 5| 5| 3| 5|
etc
```

Per each column grouping, i.e. A vs B vs C, I want to end up with three data points...

- Data Point 1: count of A1 > A2
- Data Point 2: count of A1 < A2
- Data Point 3: count of A1 == A2

What formula in Excel/Gdocs would you recommend to achieve those data points? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For reference, I looked heavily at COUNTIF and others like it, but there doesn't seem to be a way to compare a range to another range. Only ways to compare a range to a single criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do it in two steps:

Suppose this is your data, and the array is located in the range A1:B5

```
A1  A2
1   3
5   4
4   1
3   3
```

1- Type on cell D2

```
=IF(A2<B2,1,IF(A2=B2,2,IF(A2>B2,3,0)))
```

to classify the data into three conditions:

```
A1<A2 = condition 1    
A1=A2 = condition 2   
A1>A2 = condition 3
```

2- Then, use `countif` to count how many occurrences in which condition. For example, type in G2:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$5,1)
```

Here is a screenshot, to illustrate the example.

[image]